# How to Add Specific Excel Column Range to DataGridView Column that was added through "Add Column"

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am trying to import an excel worksheet column range (A1:A100) into my DataGridView "Column 1" that i have created in the DataGridView "Add Column" menu as shown in the image below:
[Add Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZBWU.jpg)

Here is the current code that i have to import my excel sheet:

```
private void ribbonButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox_path.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string pathconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source=" + textBox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR= yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathconn);
            OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [TB$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

BUT whenever i import it after i have created my custom columns, it imports the range on the right of my custom created columns as shown in the image below:
[After Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dtip.jpg)

Please can somebody help me. i just want the import data to be in the columns that i provided it

thanks a mil

Comment: Have you tried to set the `DataGridView`s  `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` before you set its `DataSource`? …dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Comment: Hi John. it seems to be populating below the right columns, however, the population is blank, like a blank excel worksheet. it seems odd? this is my new code:   MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried to set the data source to an EMPTY `DataGridView`? The code you posted appears to work fine if the grid has no columns. In this case you would need to remove the auto generate columns or set it to true. It should use the first row as column headers. What happens if you do not pre-define the columns in the grid? If nothing appears… I would look closer at the excel worksheet.

Comment: If the columns are pre-defined in the designer, make sure the `DataPropertyName` is set to match the column names you are importing. Using excel this would usually be the first row in the worksheet.